# NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.project.packaging.WarPackaging.createOtherArtifacts(WarPackaging.java:41)

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

Creating a project with Spring ROO in STS:

```
roo> project --topLevelPackage z --projectName z --java 7 --packaging WAR
Created ROOT\pom.xml
Created ROOT\src\main\resources
Created ROOT\src\main\resources\log4j.properties
Undo create ROOT\src\main\resources\log4j.properties
Undo create ROOT\src\main\resources
Undo create ROOT\pom.xml

NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.project.packaging.WarPackaging.createOtherArtifacts(WarPackaging.java:41)
```

I have reinstalled STS, and Spring Roo plugin, and changed versions but I still getting the same error...

Comment: Have a look at the source code of org.springframework.roo.project.packaging.WarPackaging ... from a brief look  applicationContextOperations seems to be null https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17572125/

Comment: On problems view:
'classpath error: unable to find org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint (check that aspectjrt.jar is in your classpath) Soep  Unknown Java Problem' But this library is on the classpath

Comment: WarPackaging NullPointerException error was solved and will be available on 1.3.1.RC2

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/commit/f23fcf5f8184c1466575d0450bc5e13b98a2c961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate project using the following, generates a WAR project and doesn't appear error:

```
project --topLevelPackage z --projectName z --java 7
```

Could you check it?

Could you create a new ticket on Spring Roo Jira with this problem?

http://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO

Best Regards,

Comment: Yes, if I don't write `--packaging WAR` It works. I can't write exactly what you say because I'm using STS and only allows me to create the project from the menu. Only when the project is created I can use the ROO console. OK I will generate a ticket. gracias.

Comment: Hi deimos1975 and thank's for your check... you can solve it generating project with ROO Shell running on System Shell and then import to STS... Thank's for create a ticket on JIRA.. i will check it!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't use ROO Shell running on system shell because I don't have Admind priveleges on the computer (to add ROO to the class PATH, etc..)

Comment: You can download Spring Roo 1.3.1.RC1 with important bug fixes from http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Comment: leaving off --packaging WAR does let the command finish, but the project isn't really setup then to be a war project

Comment: I had the same issue... Creating a new Roo project using the wizard, and setting it to generate a WAR creates a problem

Answer (score 2):

WarPackaging NullPointerException error was solved and will be available on 1.3.1.RC2

https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3566